# File drag drop MVC on embed tag

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to make my embed tag to be a dropzone. The moment I drag the file to the embed tag, I want it to change to color yellow. But this doesn't work. I want to get it working just like in Gmail where you have the text section and you can drag and drop files on it.

I’m using the [`jquery.filedrop`](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop) plugin.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dropSection").filedrop({
    fallback_id: 'btnUpload',
    fallback_dropzoneClick: true,
    url: '@Url.Action("Upload")',
    //allowedfiletypes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'application/pdf', 'application/doc'],
    allowedfileextensions: ['.doc', '.docx', '.pdf', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'],
    paramname: 'fileData',
    maxfiles: 5, //Maximum Number of Files allowed at a time.
    maxfilesize: 2, //Maximum File Size in MB.
    dragOver: function() {
      $('#dropSection').addClass('active');
    },
    dragLeave: function() {
      $('#dropSection').removeClass('active');
    },
    drop: function() {
      $('#dropSection').removeClass('active');
    },
    uploadFinished: function(i, file, response, time) {
      $('#uploadedFiles').append(file.name + '<br />')
    },
    afterAll: function(e) {
      //To do some task after all uploads done.
    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

#dropSection {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

#btnUpload {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop/master/jquery.filedrop.js"></script>

<div id="dropSection">
  <embed id="pdf" style="width:100%; height:600px;" src="~/Uploads/mypdf.pdf" />
</div>
<br />
Uploaded Files:
<hr />
<div id="uploadedFiles"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnUpload" value="Upload" />
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make this a runnable snippet, with your local resources (`~/Scripts/filedrop.js` and `~/Uploads/mypdf.pdf`) as absolute URLs?

Comment: Hi MTCoster, I don't know how I can make it runnable? But the sample code I have based this on is:
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Drag-and-Drop-multiple-File-upload-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: There's a button in the editor to add a runnable snippet - it's like using jsfiddle, but embedded here in SO

Comment: Thank you MTCoster, I couldn't add the pdf. You can use every pdf document for this example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one has a clue? It would be great if someone could help out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the problem just that it doesn’t turn yellow? That works fine for me...

Comment: Hi Mtcoster thank you for your answer. Yes that's one problem the other one is that when I drag and drop a file on the embed tag area it opens the file in stead.